# Error when using add_submenu_page in a different plugin to add_menu_page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to develop multiple plugins to fill various needs I have in WordPress. I figured I would create a 'base' plugin, and then other plugins can be installed on top.

I have created a menu page in my base plugin using add_menu_page (all this is in my class obviously, variables replaced with strings for ease of reading)

```
private function __construct() {
    add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'add_group_page'));
}

public function add_group_page(){
    add_menu_page('Group Plugins', 'Group Plugins', 'activate_plugins', 'group-plugins', array($this, 'group_page_callback'), '', 3.1415);
}

public function group_page_callback() { ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Group Plugins</h2>
    </div>
<?php
}
```

That works fine, my menu structure now has: (tags wrong on purpose, for readability of urls)

(Group Plugins)[`admin.php?page=group-plugins`]

In my second plugin, I try to call `add_submenu_page`:

```
private function __construct() {
    add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'add_groupforms_page'));
}

public function add_groupforms_page(){
    add_submenu_page('group-plugins', 'Group Forms', 'Group Forms', 'manage_options', 'group-forms', array($this, 'groupforms_page_callback'));
}

public function groupforms_page_callback() { ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Group Forms</h2>
    </div>
<?php
}
```

Which *seems* like it has worked in adding the new submenu item. But the menu structure changes to:

(Group Plugins)[`admin.php?page=**group-forms**`]

--(Group Forms)[`admin.php?page=**group-forms**`]

So both links link to the new submenu page, and when I click on either of them, I just get a backend styled page that says `You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.`

I can still access 'Group Plugins' original page if I change the slug in the url to '`group-plugins`', but something clearly isn't right, and the only thing that really shows up when I google the error is people saying to check its hooked in the right place: `admin_menu`, which it is, because I have checked the docs so many times trying to figure this out.

Comment: Ok well for now i'm just going to change my second plugins `add_submenu_page` first parameter to `null`, which hides it from being on any menu, but seems to make the actual pages both work, so I will just add it to the menu manually. better than nowt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to fire the submenu after the menu. This is done with the hook priority, when not declared defaults to `10`.

The main menu is setup with default priority:

```
add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'add_group_page'));
```

And the submenu has to be a lower priority:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', array($this, 'add_groupforms_page'), 11 );
```

Comment: Thanks that did it. Not sure why I never marked this answered